Spring boot and vue authorization header not received
I am working with spring boot server and vue.js front end and I am using axios to send my request I already did my cors policy and exposed the authorization header using the following configuration:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MainConfigurations implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final AuthorizationInterceptor authorizationInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Add cors mappings: stop cors mapping");
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders(AUTHORIZATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Add interceptors: apply interceptors");
        registry.addInterceptor(this.authorizationInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/auth/**", "/token/**");
    }
}

The request is not having a cors policy issue as it is reaching my interceptor however my problem is that the authorization header is not being detected as sent from axios however it is being detected when sent from postman and my interceptor is returning a 401 unauthorized error on OPTIONS request which is used for cors policy check yet the authorization header is received as null although it was working perfectly before without changing a thing.

Note I am adding the authorization header using axios request interceptor as follows:

axios.interceptors.request.use (
    function ( config ) {
        config.headers.setAuthorization ( Extras.token );
        config.headers.setAccept ( "application/json" );
        console.log ( config.headers );
        
        return config;
    } ,
    async function ( error ) {
        return {
            success : false ,
            message : error ,
        };
    } ,
);

still my axios doesn't send Authorization header with the request.

The solution is to tweek the interceptor to explicitly handle the OPTIONS method as such:
@Component
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @Nullable HttpServletResponse response,
            @Nullable Object handler
    ) throws Exception {
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            return true;
        }
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void postHandle(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @Nullable Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView
    ) {
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
}

This will handle the OPTIONS request sent by the browser for cors policy check.
